# Is it possible to query an OCW's Off-chain storage via RPC from an external service?

Tags: rpc, offchain-worker, indexing

I'm `off-chain` indexing some pallet events into my off-chain local storage using an `OCW`. Now, I want to be able to retrieve this data via RPC from an external service.
Is this possible? Does it require the `OCW` to access the `local-storage` as part of the RPC query?

Do `Custom RPC` work for the off-chain runtime?
https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/custom-rpcs/

Any example will be appreciate it.
TIA, Cheers!

NB: I'm not after an Oracle, I need the opposite case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Custom RPC work for the off-chain runtime. [Custom Rpc Doc](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/custom-rpcs/)
For example, you can define custom rpc in the following way:

```
#[rpc]
public trait SomeOcsApi {
  
   #[rpc(name="some_method")]
   fn some_method(params...) {
      ...
   }
}
```

And, in the implementation, just read the OCS storage

```
struct SomeOcsApiImpl<T: OffchainStorage> {
   storage: Arc<<RwLock<T>>>,
};
impl SomeOcsApi for SomeOcsApiImpl {
   value = self
            .storage
            .read()
            .get(
                sp_offchain::STORAGE_PREFIX,
                &*derive_storage_key(key.as_bytes(), &did),
            )
            .map(from_utf8)
            .unwrap_or_default();

   Ok(value)
}
```

Surely, in your OC indexer should write event to this storage also, share this reference with OC indexer.

Comment: Hi @ironman, thanks for your reply. There is a missing step in you answer that I could not figure it out yet, which is: How to extend the `RPC` into the `rpc.rs` file. There is a lot of doc, about this when you are trying to reach out the `runtime storage`, but in this case I want the `offchain storage`, something like the following snip:

`// Add a silly RPC that returns constant values io.extend_with(SomeOcsApi::to_delegate(SomeOcsApiImpl<T> ?????? )));`

TIA

Comment: @PabloBuitrago as my answer says: 
1. annotate your rpc trait with #[rpc]
2. annotate your rpc method with #[rpc]
3. impl the rpc trait, with the Off-Chain Storage as a field.
4. in your node/rpc.rs, config the delegate to your defined rpc.

For step 1-3, you can take [our rpc](https://github.com/parami-protocol/parami-blockchain/blob/main/pallets/did/rpc/src/lib.rs) as reference;
For step4, you cant take [our node rpc](https://github.com/parami-protocol/parami-blockchain/blob/main/nodes/dana/src/rpc.rs) as reference.

Comment: Thanks @ironman. Congrats! or Parami. Looks promising.

Comment: A common suggestion is when you encounter how-to-use problem, alway go to substrate/Polkadot/Acala/Parami's repository, search a example.

Comment: Great suggestion! Once more, thank you @ironman.