# How to extend a `custom RPC` service to query the `off-chain` storage?

Tags: rpc, offchain-storage

There are many docs/tutorials explaining how to extend the node's RPC service with a Custom RPC to query the Runtime storage. What I could not figure it out yet, is how to do the same but to query the Offchain-storage. I basically want to replicate the following available built-in service but with my own Custom RPC:
https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_rpc_api/offchain/index.html

Below are my snippets:

This example works properly. No storage required.

```
// node/src/rpc.rs
// Ref: https://substrate.recipes/custom-rpc.html

let mut io = jsonrpc_core::IoHandler::default();

// Add a silly RPC that returns constant values
io.extend_with(SillyRpc::to_delegate(Silly {},));
```

The following example is the one I'm interested in, and I could not figure it out how to make it work so far. Below I'm trying to incorporate the `offchain-storage`.

```
// node/src/rpc.rs
// Ref: https://core.tetcoin.org/rustdocs/v2.0.1/src/sc_rpc/offchain/mod.rs.html

let mut io = jsonrpc_core::IoHandler::default();

let storage = ???????
io.extend_with(SillyRpc::to_delegate(Silly::new(storage)));
```

The closest code I found similar to what I need is the following from `builder.rs`:

```
let maybe_offchain_rpc = offchain_storage.map(|storage| {
    let offchain = sc_rpc::offchain::Offchain::new(storage, deny_unsafe);
    offchain::OffchainApi::to_delegate(offchain)
});
```

Also related to the previous question:
[Is it possible to query an OCW's Off-chain storage via RPC from an external service?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/is-it-possible-to-query-an-ocws-off-chain-storage-via-rpc-from-an-external-serv/1049#1049)

Regards,
Pablo.

Comment: FYI that existing rustdoc link I updated to https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_rpc_api/offchain/index.html - there is a different API exposed than before, please do check there for the new stuff, and update your question as needed?

Comment: Also all `https://core.tetcoin.org/` links are unmaintained by a 3rd party that should not be referenced.

Comment: Closing this question because it is stale. If you have a similar question, please open an new post, which will get eyes on it again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is stale.